# Can we unstake all of staked eos tokens?

Tags: bandwidth

I have an account with 90 eos staked for cpu bandwidth, and it shows 7 ms used with this account. My question is that is it possible to unstake all the 90 eos?

Comment: Good question! I think if you are able to unstake the full amount, your account may be unusable afterwards. In Steem, accounts become unusable once the staked amount gets too low, so leaving a little is recommended. Perhaps the cpu usage ensures you can't unstake too much, and will reserve a couple of EOS for operations.

Answer (score 3):

The unstake command will become available after at least 15% of the total token holders vote on the chain.  Right now, were almost at 7% (https://eosauthority.com/voting), so no one can unstake their tokens. Thomas Cox elaborates on this in his post Magic 15%.

> "And even after we hit 15% and the “unstake” command becomes
>   available, it takes three days for unstaking of tokens used for CPU or
>   bandwidth."

https://medium.com/@thomas.cox_39839/magic-15-unlocking-the-eosio-blockchain-91ec54f7b48d

Answer (score 1):

Voting requires Staked tokens and when voting is ended, you will be able to unstake them.

However, Staked tokens require a 3-day liquidation.